# PL/SQL concatenate items of varray, or items of table, with delimiters

Tags: arrays, string, oracle, plsql

I have these PL/SQL (Oracle) types

```
type StrArray is varray(1000) of varchar(1000);
type StrTable is table of varchar(1000);
```

and the variables:

```
array1 StrArray := StrArray();
array2 StrTable := StrTable();
joinedStr1 varchar(10000);
joinedStr2 varchar(10000);
```

I can join all the items in StrArray or StrTable with a 'for' loop and add the delimiters in. But I'm looking for a ready-to-use function in PL/SQL for this purpose. Are there any?

Comment: If you are trying to take a collection and return a comma-separated string and you are using a SQL collection type (it's not clear whether your nested table is a SQL or a PL/SQL collection) you could use the `listagg` analytic function.  I would seriously question, though, why you would want to do that in the first place-- that would generally imply to me that you're doing something inefficiently.  A collection should be vastly easier to use in PL/SQL than a comma-separated string.

Comment: i want to make the list to use in 'select ... where id in (...)

Comment: can we use pl/sql table in 'where .. in ..' clause?

Comment: If the collection is defined in SQL and the Oracle version is prior to 12.1, yes.  If the Oracle version is 12.1 or later, you have much more flexibility to use PL/SQL collections in SQL.  It's not clear to me whether your nested table is defined in SQL or just in PL/SQL.  And if it is defined in PL/SQL, it's not clear whether there is any reason not to define the collection in SQL instead.